# Is it possible to simulate the event of anchors (html) with the Android interface (xml)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, anchor

Is it possible to simulate the event of anchors (html) with the Android interface?
I mean I have a listview with several titles and I want to press a button that moves the screen to the specific title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the position of the item in the List, you can use `setSelection()` in your button's click handler.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29